# Equivalent of .where without Query in before_save - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `Invoice` model which `accepts_nested_attributes_for` `:line_items` with `allow_destroy: true`. In my model, in a `before_save` callback, I can reference the data like this:

```
self.line_items
```

Some of the items will be deleted upon save. I want to be able to grab only the items that won't be deleted like this:

```
self.line_items.where(_destroy: false)
```

However, this obviously won't work since I am dealing with an unsaved object. So, my question is how do I get the list of items that won't be deleted? I know I could technically iterate through the list and add each applicable item to a new array, but I figure there is something more intuitive. For example, currently I use `.sort_by(&:line_number)` rather than the SQL `.sort(:line_number)` for sorting which allows me to sort in memory rather than from SQL. I need the same thing except for a `.where` clause.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the condition that makes a line_item to be destroyed? for instance price = 0? How is it decided which line_items have to be kept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, `where` is aimed specifically at building SQL queries, so you can't use it to deal with in-memory criteria like whether something will be destroyed on save. For that, you can use the methods in the [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Enumerable.html) module, which is included in the collection object. The `sort_by` call you mentioned is using that module. In this case, you'd probably use `line_items.reject(&:marked_for_destruction?)`. See the [documentation for `marked_for_destruction?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html#method-i-marked_for_destruction-3F) for more details.